# How to path an absolute path to System.Net.Mail Attachment constructor instead of using default .exe path

Tags: c#, .net

I am wanting to pass the path of a log file to the Attachment constructor, and I need to use the absolute path since this log is not located in the same directory as the project.  When I pass the fully qualified, absolute path, the constructor appends the path to the debug folder in front of my absolute path and it obviously throws an exception since that path does not exist.

I have used this method before to add files with external paths and have not seen this issue before.  I can verify in the debugger that the path I pass to the constructor is accurate,  yet the exception shows the appended system path on top of my absolute path.  I am working in Parallels which I wonder if that is causing any issues.

```
if(attachments != null)
{
   foreach(string a in attachments)
   {
       try
       {
           var att = new Attachment(a);
           mail.Attachments.Add(att);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           log.Error(ex.Message); 
       }

    }
 }
```

The exception is thrown by the constructor and since it is a system class I cannot inspect any further to diagnose the issue.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `attachments`? Could you show the values of `attachments` and `a` which produce this behaviour?

Comment: attachments is a List<string> object which contains the file paths.  There is only one string in the collection in this use case.  In my scenario, a = \\Mac\Home\Documents\TaskEngine.log @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: Can you show the path assigned to the absolute path?

Comment: @MobrineHayde the value of "a" I posted in my previous comment is the value of the absolute path